# Brute forcing XOR key that will meet my requirements

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have an issue with my code, as I'm trying to find the byte which is within ASCII printable range that would satisfy my requirements which is if the 2 bytes 1 from my predefined string XORed with 1 from the ascii range and take the sum it should be 0x210 (528 in decimal) but I couldn't get it to work

let me explain it a bit more 
I have a string of "AABBCCDDEE" and the ascii range (33,128)
if each byte xored with 1 or more byte in the ascii range and added all the xored operation it would give me an output of 0x210

this is my trial and it keeps adding to result variable even though I set a condition

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
import random

asciiRange = list(range(33,128))
fixedKey = "aCaCaCaCaC"
hKey = []
result = 0

for i in fixedKey:
    hKey.append(ord(i))

while result != 528:
    key = random.choice(asciiRange)
    print result
    for i in hKey:
        result += i ^ key
        print result
        if result > 528:
            break
```

Comment: `take the sum` over what? How do you expect any precise value when you use `random.choice(asciiRange)`?

Comment: I do not, because I want to randomly select a value xor it with the predefined string and add each time to the result variable, and check if the result is equal to my requirement 0x210 (528) I wish you got the idea :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the break does stop the `for`-loop, but you still need to add a break to get out of the `while`-loop, since result will likely not equal `528`.

Furthermore, the `if` statement will break out of the loop under the same conditions, so `while`-loop is not necessary:

```
key = random.choice(asciiRange)
print result
for i in hKey:
    result += i ^ key
    print result
    if result > 528:
        break
```

Or you could change `while`-loop condition to: `while result <= 528:`

Comment: I don't get it. Do you always break from loop in the last line?

Comment: Yes if the conditions are met you do

Comment: Let me rephrase: your while-loop always does at most one iteration. Why do you need while-loop at all?

Comment: Ah yes you are right, the `while`-loop is unnecessary and can be removed. thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Thank you so much, How can I then possibly select 2,3,4 random values from the asscii range to achieve the requirements ? do I need to design an algorithm or am i thinking too much ? b/c I had this problem and I had to do it manually so I took the chance to improve programming skills through such an issue

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can select `N` random values using [random.sample(range, N)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample) to get `N` random values: `random.sample(asciiRange, N)`, then replace `N` with `2`,`3`,`4` or however many samples you want. Is that what you are describing?

Comment: no what I mean is that let's assume 2 bytes of asccii printable range can achieve the requirement of having 528 at the end, how can I find out which 2 bytes would make that ? do I need to get into algorithm and data structure or there is a way out of it without ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't set `result` to 0 before each iteration. Here is a code which works with small refactorings.

```
 import random

 asciiRange = list(range(33,128))
 hKey = [ord(c) for c in "AABBCCDDEE"]

 val = 508
 while True:
     result = 0
     key = random.choice(asciiRange)
     for i in hKey:
         result += i ^ key
         if result > val:
             break
     print(result, end=' ')
     if result == val:
         break
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but also the same to achieve same result regardless of what keys being selected from the list do I need to design an algorithm to sort this out or nah ?